# implementing a recursive reverse function in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that reverses a list. The function is recursive.

I know javascript does not have TCO, but i wanted to experiment with this anyway:

```
reverse = function(list) {
    if (list.length < 2) { return list }
    fk = fork(list);
    return reverse(fk.tail).concat([fk.head])
}
```

the `fork` function splits a list to a head and a tail:

```
fork = function(list) {return {head: list[0], tail: list.slice(1)}}
```

When I call `reverse()` with the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`, I get this result:

```
reverse([1,2,3,4,5]) // [5,4,4,4,4]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The expected result is `[5,4,3,2,1]`.

Please help.

Comment: You know this is already built in natively as [`Array.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: I know this, but i wanted to build it myself in scholarly interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should lint your code, that'll help you tremendously. In particular, this code fails because `fk` is treated as a global variable. If you prefix it with `var`, it works:

```
var reverse = function(list) {
    if (list.length < 2) { return list }
    var fk = fork(list);
    return reverse(fk.tail).concat([fk.head])
}
```

As it stands now, at each recursive call you modify the same `fk` variable, essentially meaning concating the same `fk.head` - the element before the last one.

---

In fact, you don't even need temporary variable here:

```
function recursive_reverse(list) {
  return list.length < 2 ? list : recursive_reverse(list.slice(1)).concat([list[0]]);
}
```

---

As for tail recursion, here's one possible approach:

```
function recursive_reverse(list) {
  return tail_recursive_reverse(list, []);
}

function tail_recursive_reverse(list, res) {
  if (!list.length) return res;
  var head = list[0];
  var tail = list.slice(1);
  res.unshift(head);
  return tail_recursive_reverse(tail, res);
}
```

Comment: this line `return tail_recursive_reverse(tail, (res.unshift(head), res));` calls the tail recursive function with 3 arguments instead of two. Did you mean for the last two to be in an array?

Comment: No, it's two arguments there; the second one is the result of comma expression (that is its second operand - `res`). Parentheses are for a reason there. )

Comment: What is the need for the comma expression?

Comment: `res.unshift(head)` returns a new length of an array, not an array itself. But in this case, one wants `res` to be passed further. Of course, it's not necessary, one can just write `res.unshift(head)` as a standalone expression. I've rewritten, as it seems to cause a confusion.

Comment: interesting... i didnt know one could do that. thanks for the explanation.