# Reverse function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the reverse of this array, in this case ([4,3,2,1]). The problem is I can use no reverse or other shorcuts.

```
const ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const reverse = function (arr) {


    let x = arr;

        for(i=0; i<x.length;i++) {

        x[x.length-i-1]=x[i];


        }
return x;   
};

const reversedArray = reverse(ar);
console.log(reversedArray);
```

I thought it must be working, however when I run I get [ 1, 2, 2, 1 ]
as an output. Which is because when i=1 at the second index there is no longer 3. What can I do?

Comment: `ar.reverse()` comes to mind ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.reverse`

Comment: Reverse in another array.

Comment: run the array up to `x.length/2` over two and swap `x[i]` and `x[x.length-i-1]`

Comment: @adeneo the essence of the probelem is to use no helpers, or shortcuts

Comment: @Paulpro but the array is changed

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan It doesn't matter that the array gets changed if you only iterate half way anyway. See Clyde's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implementing a recursive reverse function in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183842/implementing-a-recursive-reverse-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example. But you can achieve the same result with other methods.

```
function reverse(array){
    var new_array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
        new_array[i] = array[array.length -i - 1];
    }
    return new_array;
}

//how to use
reverse([1,2,3,4,5]); //output
```

Answer (score 2):

It's like swapping two variables without using a temp variable

```js
const ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const reverse = function (arr) {


    let x = arr, len = x.length-1;

        for(i=0; i<x.length/2;i++) {

          x[i]+=x[len-i];
          x[len-i]=x[i]-x[len-i];
          x[i]-=x[len-i]


        }
return x;   
};

const reversedArray = reverse(ar);
console.log(reversedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it simple by using a regular `for` loop, and then just `unshift`ing the values onto a new array:

```js
function reverse(arr) {
  let reversed = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    reversed.unshift(arr[i]);
  }
  return reversed;
}


console.log(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(reverse([6, 7, 8, 9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `while loop` and *starting* from the end of the array :

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function arrReverse(arr) {
  var res = [];
  var max = arr.length - 1;
  while (max > -1) {
    res.push(arr[max]);
    max -= 1;
  }
  return res;
}

var res = arrReverse(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the array while you do that because of Javascript's references.

You can use array.prototype.reverse (which is used as [].reverse())
Or you should set a new array and return it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the array as a constant. It is probably not letting you make changes in the array.

Then use the reverse method:

```
ar.reverse();
```

Comment: From the question: "**The problem is I can use no `reverse` or other shorcuts.**"